# Closure of Normal Subgroups of the Galois Group for an Infinite Galois Extension is Normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let K/F be an infinite Galois extension, and let N be a normal sub-group of Gal(K/F). Show that N closure is a normal subgroup of Gal(K/F).

Comment: the closure of a normal subgroup in any topological group is normal

Comment: I have this proof. But can we do it w/o topological group?

Comment: Without topology, what do you mean by closure?

Comment: I am seeking a proof using Fundamental Theorem of Infinite Galois Theory. Possibly by showing Fixed field of N closure is Galois over F.

Comment: Okay!! I have got it. Thanks, anyway!